# How to retrieve Wikidata entry from Wikidata search results?

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

I make a Wikidata search request like this (autocomplete use case):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&format=json&language=en&type=item&continue=0&search=photog
```

And the service returns a JSON response thus

```
{
    id: "Q11633",
    url: "//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11633",
    description: "art, science and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation",
    label: "photography"
}
```

But how do I look up to get retrieve the content?

I can only find a `title` search which does not recognize the Q parameter. It only recognizes titles.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Photography
```

Comment: This is what you want to use: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `wbgetentities`, another method of WikiData's extension to the MediaWiki API ([WikiBase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API)). In its most basic form, it looks like this:

```
api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q11633
```

You probably want to reduce the size of the reply, by specifying what you what to know about the entity, using [the `props` parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API#wbgetentities).

Comment: what are the ids for?? '

Comment: @kumuda That's the id's for the entities you want to look up. Like `Q11633` in the question